# How do I use DateDetailView with a slug to render a page with a single article?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am new to Django, and I am trying to have a separate page where I can view individual articles.  Currently I have:

```
#views.py
class ArticleView(DateDetailView):
    template_name = 'blog/article.html'
    model = Article
    date_field = "pub_date"
    #I am not sure which one to use
    slug_field = "unique_url_suffix"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'unique_url_suffix'
```

and

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(index\.html)?$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[-\w]+)/(?P<day>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
 views.ArticleView.as_view(),
 name="article_detail"),
]
```

and in `index.html` inside a loop of objects from the `Article` class:

```
<h2><a href= "{% url 'blog:article_detail' article %}">{{article.title}}</a></h2>
```

I have also tried manually inputting the arguments, like this:

```
<h2><a href= "{% url 'blog:article_detail' date_field=article.pub_date slug=article.unique_url_suffix %}">{{article.title}}</a></h2>
```

I keep on getting a "NoReverseMatch at /blog/" error. What am I doing incorrectly?

Edit:  On top of the changes recommended for the answer, there was a typo causing problems.  It does not affect the answer below, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should not be generating this URL in your template. You should define a [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method in your `Article` model that looks like this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
    # Note - you have to supply each of the date components separately
    # because you need to match the URL regex.
    return reverse (
        'blog:article_detail', 
        kwargs={'year': self.pub_date.strftime("%Y"), 'month': self.pub_date.strftime("%b"), 
        'day': self.pub_date.strftime("%d"), 'slug': self.unique_url_suffix}
    )
```

And then in your template:

```
<h2><a href= "{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">{{article.title}}</a></h2>
```

Comment: I made those changes, but I am getting an Attribute Error that says,

`Generic detail view ArticleView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.`

Is there something in views.py that should be updated/overridden, like the get_object() method?

Comment: Nevermind.  I had a typo in the `ArticleView` class for the slug field.  The problem has been resolved, and this looks like a cleaner way to organize things.  Thinks.